# Vue 3 Typescript Composition API: Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Using Vue 3's Composition API, I want to temporarily display the local selected photo as the button's background image. Upon uploading, the `style.backgroundImage` will return to its default.

The first set of errors I was running into was the `Object is possibly 'null'` on `photo.value` & `e.target`. I resolved these with a conditional. Let me know if this is not Vue 3 best practice.

The current error I am facing is the `Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.` on `e.target.files[0]`. Is this a type declaration issue? How would this be best resolved?

The online solution `(<HTMLInputElement>e.target).files[0]` does not seem to work for Vue. Returns `Object is possibly 'null'.`

```
<template>
    <button ref="photo" @click="uploadPhoto"></button>
    <input type="file" ref="photoInput" @change="showTempPhoto" style="display: none" />
</template>
```

```js
setup(){
    const photo = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)
    const photoInput = ref<HTMLInputElement | null>(null)

    const uploadPhoto = () => {
        photoInput.value?.click()
    }

    const showTempPhoto = (e: Event) => {
        if (photo.value && e.target){
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
            photo.value.style.backgroundImage = url
            photo.value.onload = () => URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The class `Event` may or may not have a target as shown here:

```js
let my_event = new Event('event_type');
console.log(my_event.target)

// outputs null
```

And typescript does not know either the element type of the target or if it is not null; so you would have to check **explicitly** if `target` is not `null` and cast `e.target` to `HTMLInputElement`:

```js
const showTempPhoto = (e: Event) => {
    if (photo.value && e.target !== null){
        const url = URL.createObjectURL((<HTMLInputElement>e.target).files[0])
        photo.value.style.backgroundImage = url
        photo.value.onload = () => URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the online solution I tried, but received `Object is possibly 'null'.` I believe it may be a Vue-specific issue.

Comment: have you checked for null explicitly? Could you show the full error log? What version of ts are you using?

Comment: Figured it out. I needed to deconstruct the url declaration. However, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Deconstructing the url declaration helped me to resolved the issue.

```js
const target = <HTMLInputElement>e.target
```

Followed by a `null` check,

```js
const url = URL.createObjectURL(target.files && target.files[0])
```

then finally a clean-up of the `backgroundImage` assignment

```js
photo.value.style.backgroundImage = `url('${url}')`
```